# Immediately got back to Main Activity Even before finished job in Second Activity

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I am developing a reminder app.In my Main Activity there is a floating action button to go to Second Activity.In Second Activity, the user can write text, set specific time to remind him and also the user can save the text.And when the user click save button, the activity will go back to Main Activity and the text will be saved in Main Activity.My problem here is after the user set time in Time Picker Dialog in Second Activity and even before the user click Save button the activity immediately go back to Main Activity.I tried different method ways I know and spend a lot of time in this problem.But could not find the error yet.Please help if someone know my problem.I really appreciate your guys help.
[Here is Main Activity Screen Shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxbeT.png)  [Here is Second Activity Screen Shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyVtn.png)

Here is My codes.

```
package com.doflamingo.alarm;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private SQLiteDatabase mdatabase;
    private AlarmAdapter malarmAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(this);
        mdatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        RecyclerView mrecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        malarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(this, getAllItems());
        mrecyclerView.setAdapter(malarmAdapter);


        FloatingActionButton buttonAddAlarm = findViewById(R.id.button_add_alarm);
        buttonAddAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }

    private Cursor getAllItems(){
        return  mdatabase.query(
                AlarmContract.AlarmEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                AlarmContract.AlarmEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"
        );
    }

}




public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mMessage;
    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Button mOpenTimePicker;
    private Button mSaveAlarm;
    private static int id;
    private SQLiteDatabase mdatabase;
    private AlarmAdapter malarmAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        mMessage = findViewById(R.id.edittext_message);
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);
        setTitle("Add Alarm");
        AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(this);
        mdatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        mOpenTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_alarm);
        mOpenTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TimePicker();
            }
        });

        Button mbuttonCancel = findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
        mbuttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancelAlarm();
            }
        });

        mSaveAlarm = findViewById(R.id.button_save_alarm);
        mSaveAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveAlarm();
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveAlarm(){
        String message = mMessage.getText().toString();
       String text =  mTextView.getText().toString();

        if(text.trim().isEmpty()||message.trim().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(AlarmContract.AlarmEntry.COLUMN_TEXT,text );
        cv.put(AlarmContract.AlarmEntry.COLUMN_MESSAGE,message);

        mdatabase.insert(AlarmContract.AlarmEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        malarmAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());
        Intent intent =  new Intent(AlarmActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    private Cursor getAllItems(){
        return  mdatabase.query(
                AlarmContract.AlarmEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                AlarmContract.AlarmEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"
        );
    }

    private void TimePicker(){
        final Calendar date;
        final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = Calendar.getInstance();
        new DatePickerDialog(AlarmActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                new TimePickerDialog(AlarmActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                        Log.v(TAG, "The choosen one " + date.getTime());
                                startAlarm(date);
//                                DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
                        mTextView.setText((CharSequence) date.getTime());

                    }
                }, currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
            }
        }, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DATE)).show();

    }

    private void startAlarm(Calendar c) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //Passing data
        String message = mMessage.getText().toString();
        id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("Message", message);
        intent.putExtra("ID", id);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }

    private void cancelAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        mTextView.setText("Alarm canceled");
        mMessage.setText("");
    }

}


public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String message;
    private static int ID;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        message = intent.getStringExtra("Message");
        ID = intent.getIntExtra("ID",0);

              NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
              NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannel1Notification(message);
              notificationHelper.getManager().notify(ID,nb.build());

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate activity here? Would a fullsceen dialog or a fragment not be more convenient here?

Comment: The problem should be related to your `startAlarm` method. When you delete this line, does it still switch the `activity` immediately?

Comment: @cewaphi Yeah bro I also thought that was the problem.I thought some kind of pending intent error.I closed the start Alarm and still the error did not appear.